# How can I add roles to service account in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using service account credential to deploy `cloud function` to GCP. I got a permission error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Missing necessary permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for $MEMBER on the service account
```

I open the service account permission in GCP but I can't find where I can add the role to the account.

Below is the screenshot of the service account. There is `GRANT ACCESS` button but it is used to grant member access to this account. How can I add roles on the role list?

[image]

Comment: The `actAs` permission means that you are granting an IAM identity (user, service account, group, etc.) the ability to impersonate the service account. The service account is a resource in this case. You must grant the IAM identity permission `on the service account` and not as a permission at the project level. An example role is `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`. This document will help you add an identity to the service account with the required role.  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#allow-impersonation

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2023:

1. Go to IAM & Admin -> IAM
2. Under "View by principals" you will find all accounts, including service accounts
3. Press the edit button on the right side of your service account
4. Select "Add another roll" and add the role you want your service account to have

Answer (score 0):

Recapping what John said:
You do not need to grant permissions to the Service Account.
You need to grant permission to user so that they can act as that Service Account.
**TL;DR:**
On the screen you provided, select **Grant access**, enter username and pick **Service Account User** role.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP question. He needs to add roles to the service account so the service account has authorization to do things on GCP. This answer is not addressing that.